# HTML not displaying as expected in outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <table align="center" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="600"  style="text-align: center;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="height:78px; width:528px">
                    <a href="Link" style="display:block; height:78px; width:528px; color: #2a3379; text-decoration: none !important; padding-top:32px; font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; border-radius:5px; font-size:40px; display:block; margin:0 auto; background-color:#B5E61D;">                                                     
                        Apply now
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
```

Which display like this in the browser:

[image]

The problem is, that when I add it as an HTML template to an email, it displays like this in outlook:

[image]

From what I have read, I know outlook does not render HTML very well. I also read not to use CSS and to inline all the styling - but this has not worked.

The email needs to be responsive, so I would prefer not to use an image.

I guess there is a particular rule that is causing this problem.

Has anyone come across this before and found a good solution?

Comment: @PhilippSander it is already structured like that - I am just editing an existing template

Comment: @PhilippSander because its an email.

Comment: @Alex, `display` properties in emails are not supported across all clients. Especially outlook. See what is supported here https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/b/

Comment: If all else fails, use a larger cellpadding. (Disclaimer: I don't have Outlook here, so can't test.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have placed the padding on the A and not td, thats your issue here.
So I have changed a bit in the bit for getting it to work. Everything regarding background color and height/width needs to be on the TD and not the A. Only the text related styles should be there :)

```
<html>
    <table align="center" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="600"  style="text-align: center;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" height="78" width="528" style="display:block; padding:32px 0px; display:block; background-color:#B5E61D; border-radius:5px;">
                    <a href="#" style="color: #2a3379; text-decoration: none !important;  font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; font-size:40px;">                                                     
                        Apply now
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
```

As a note, remember border-radius dosnt work in outlooks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this into your head:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
     body {mso-line-height-rule: exactly;}
     tr {mso-line-height-rule: exactly;}
     td{mso-line-height-rule: exactly;}
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
  <!--[if gte mso 15]>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
    body{font-size:0;line-height:0;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;}
    tr{font-size:0px;mso-line-height-alt:0px;mso-margin-top-alt:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;}
    td{mso-line-height-rule:exactly;}
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
```

Coding in Outlook is weird as it uses the Word engine to render html from 2007 on (no idea why).

Quick tip, if you open your html file in Word, you can get a preview of what it will look like in the corresponding Outlook.

EDIT: Just noticed you only have your background color on your anchor link, be sure to include it in your `td` also.

Answer (score 0):

remove `padding` & Add `line-height`

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="600"  style="text-align: center;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="width:528px">
                    <a href="Link" style="display:block; height:100px; line-height:100px;  width:528px; color: #2a3379; text-decoration: none !important; font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; border-radius:5px; font-size:40px; display:block; margin:0 auto; background-color:#B5E61D;">                                                     
                        Apply now
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Just found out yesterday that Line-height dosnt work in outlook 2016 :-(

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup It should, but like the previous Outlook versions, you need to include `mso-line-height-rule:exactly;` https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/coding-for-outlook-2016